# Is is possible to load an external ASP page then perform a submit to an ASP pages form

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net

I would like to perform a search via GET from one website's html form to another ASP.net page's form that's on a different webpage. Is this possible?

I want to do this for this website:
http://www.fasnetdirect.com/kaneprls.asp?Page=home

After inspecting element of the search box that says "Search by keywords*" I get the following html tag:

```
<input type="text" name="SearchString" size="50">
```

I will have a GET submit form that will query a string over to that search form "Search by keywords*" and have that submitted. So If you search something on my website, it will enter in the string the user typed in on my website, inject it into that "Search by keywords*" input area then automatically hit "search".

Is this possible to do with either PHP, or JavaScript? and if so, what is this called?

Comment: you might look at ajax though from the sounds of it you will run into cross-domain issues...

Comment: You need to perform the search server-side using XMLHTTP.